# Why does setText() change the contentType of a Document?

Tags: plone

When I change the text e.g. in a Document with `setText()` the content type of the Document is changed to `text/plain`.

```python
In [1]: app.Plone.invokeFactory('Document', 'doc')
Out[1]: 'doc'

In [2]: app.Plone.doc.getContentType()
Out[2]: 'text/html'

In [3]: app.Plone.doc.setText('xyz'); app.Plone.doc.getContentType()
Out[3]: 'text/plain'

In [4]: app.Plone.doc.setText('<abc>xyz</abc>'); app.Plone.doc.getContentType()
Out[4]: 'text/html'
```

Even if I create a Document and I set the `mimetype` explicitly to `text/plain` it changes the type to `text/html`.

```python
In [1]: app.Plone.invokeFactory('Document', 'doc', 
                                 text='<abc>xyz</abc>', 
                                 mimetype='text/plain')
Out[1]: 'doc'

In [2]: app.Plone.doc.getContentType()
Out[2]: 'text/html'
```

The text is processed by `_process_input()` of the `TextField(FileField)` class and it guess the type and changes it.

Does the API expects the programmer to know about all the guesses of `_process_input()`? If yes, is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

i guess your doument is an ATContentTypes document.

in this case, the default mimetype is used unless a specific mimetype is given in setText:

`doc.setText(u"<p>your text</p>", mimetype='text/html')`

see https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/2.2.0/Products/ATContentTypes/content/document.py#L112

for uploaded documents, the mimetype gets guessed
https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/2.2.0/Products/ATContentTypes/content/document.py#L137

Comment: It seems that there is no "default" mimetype but that the mimetype is allways guessed by the field's `_process_input`. See my second example where the content type is changed even though it is given in `invokeFactory`. See also my first example where the content type is guessed and changed. This means that the programmer **must know** about how those guesses work and which changes they make!

Comment: the guessing seems to happen in https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/2.2.0/Products/ATContentTypes/content/document.py#L137 not in the textfield. set a tracepoint there and debug what's happening.

Comment: `guessMimetypeOfText()` is called only by `manage_afterAdd()` and therefore it explains the guess after creation and call of `manage_afterAdd()` but `guessMimetypeOfText()` is not calles when using `invokeFactory()`.
Actually it is `setText()` (a `FileField`s method) that if called without `mimetype` calls `_process_input()` -> `mimetipes.guess_content_type()` -> `mimetipes.guess_type` etc. and adds `mimetype` returned to kwargs.